# Raspbian compile single kernel module gfs2

Tags: raspbian, linux, kernel, mount, modules

I'm trying my best to get GFS2 mounted on top of a dual-primary DRDB `/dev/drdb0` volume on Raspbian, but I'm hitting an issue. The DRBD volume has a working `stonith`/`fencing` cluster setup using `pacemaker` and works fine on that side. The cluster is successfully synced across both RPi nodes, in a `Primary/Primary` configuration.

Note: I have gotten this setup to work using `ocfs2`, but I would really like to get `gfs2` working.

Whenever I format `/dev/drbd0` using mkfs.gfs2` and then try to mount the GFS2 volume, I get an error:

```
mount -t gfs2 -o noatime,nodiratime,noquota /dev/drbd0 /data
mount: mount(2) failed: /data: No such file or directory
```

I've read up about this and there seems scant information about this. I have determined that the linux kernel config file `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.79+/.config` shows this as an unconfigured part of the kernel module:

```
CONFIG_GFS2_FS=m
# CONFIG_GFS2_FS_LOCKING_DLM is not set
```

I think this means it needs to be enabled to `CONFIG_GFS2_FS_LOCKING_DLM=y` and recompiled.

I am running into a lot of issues with 1) determining the correct module and 2) getting it correctly compiled and installed.
I think it is part of `fs/gfs2` or `fs/dlm`.

After setting the `.config` file, I have been trying to compile them using the commands:

```
make modules SUBDIRS=fs/dlm
make modules_install SUBDIRS=fs/dlm
make modules SUBDIRS=fs/gfs2
make modules_install SUBDIRS=fs/gfs2
```

Then:

```
modprobe dlm
modprobe gfs2
```

Still I get the same errors when trying to mount the filesystem.

I'm stuck, can anyone help?

**Update: Adding output for use of answer by @Ingo** (Thanks for responding).

```
root@raspberrypi4:~# sudo modprobe dlm

root@raspberrypi4:~# sudo modprobe gfs2

root@raspberrypi4:~# lsmod | egrep 'dlm|gfs2'
gfs2                  334544  0
dlm                   153064  8

root@raspberrypi4:~# sudo ls -al /data/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 13:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Jan 22 13:36 ..

root@raspberrypi4:~# mkfs.gfs2 -p lock_dlm -j 2 -t nfs:nfs /dev/drbd0
-su: mkfs.gfs2: command not found

root@raspberrypi4:~# apt-get install gfs2-utils -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gfs2-utils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 237 kB of archives.
After this operation, 946 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mirror.serverius.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf gfs2-utils armhf 3.1.9-2 [237 kB]
Fetched 237 kB in 9s (24.5 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package gfs2-utils.
(Reading database ... 75111 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gfs2-utils_3.1.9-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking gfs2-utils (3.1.9-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up gfs2-utils (3.1.9-2) ...

root@raspberrypi4:~# mkfs.gfs2 -p lock_dlm -j 2 -t nfs:nfs /dev/drbd0
/dev/drbd0: Read-only file system

root@raspberrypi4:~# cat /proc/drbd
version: 8.4.10 (api:1/proto:86-101)
srcversion: 7EBAF95052116ECFD37C687
 0: cs:Connected ro:Secondary/Secondary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:265164 nr:0 dw:265164 dr:3104 al:33 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:d oos:0

root@raspberrypi4:~# drbdadm primary nfs

root@raspberrypi4:~# cat /proc/drbd
version: 8.4.10 (api:1/proto:86-101)
srcversion: 7EBAF95052116ECFD37C687
 0: cs:Connected ro:Primary/Secondary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:265164 nr:0 dw:265164 dr:3104 al:33 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:d oos:0

root@raspberrypi4:~# mkfs.gfs2 -p lock_dlm -j 2 -t nfs:nfs /dev/drbd0
It appears to contain an existing filesystem (ocfs2)
This will destroy any data on /dev/drbd0
Are you sure you want to proceed? [y/n]y
Discarding device contents (may take a while on large devices): Done
Adding journals: Done
Building resource groups: Done
Creating quota file: Done
Writing superblock and syncing: Done
Device:                    /dev/drbd0
Block size:                4096
Device size:               3.73 GB (978377 blocks)
Filesystem size:           3.73 GB (978374 blocks)
Journals:                  2
Resource groups:           16
Locking protocol:          "lock_dlm"
Lock table:                "nfs:nfs"
UUID:                      bcd37508-ad9b-28cd-ee37-bbe020b7ae4e

root@raspberrypi4:~# sudo mount -t gfs2 -o noatime,nodiratime,noquota /dev/drbd0 /data
mount: mount(2) failed: /data: No such file or directory

root@raspberrypi4:~# dmesg | tail -60
[    3.563656] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
[    3.610066] random: systemd-cryptse: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.740742] uart-pl011 20201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[    4.453683] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    4.474723] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    4.493617] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    4.507598] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    4.520857] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    4.534018] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    4.547161] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    4.647540] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[    4.717381] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 7827456 512-byte logical blocks: (4.01 GB/3.73 GiB)
[    4.717912] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    4.717931] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[    4.718439] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[    4.718458] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    4.727793]  sda: sda1
[    4.733347] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    7.287521] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    7.874193] systemd-journald[88]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    7.977196] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   10.981582] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   11.040548] bcm2835_alsa bcm2835_alsa: card created with 8 channels
[   15.313181] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   16.837859] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC5E1
[   19.067119] random: crng init done
[   19.067142] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   24.793040] drbd: initialized. Version: 8.4.10 (api:1/proto:86-101)
[   24.793062] drbd: srcversion: 7EBAF95052116ECFD37C687
[   24.793069] drbd: registered as block device major 147
[   26.243493] drbd nfs: Starting worker thread (from drbdsetup-84 [452])
[   26.261886] block drbd0: disk( Diskless -> Attaching )
[   26.262112] drbd nfs: Method to ensure write ordering: drain
[   26.262313] block drbd0: max BIO size = 122880
[   26.270502] block drbd0: drbd_bm_resize called with capacity == 7827016
[   26.270677] block drbd0: resync bitmap: bits=978377 words=30576 pages=30
[   26.270696] block drbd0: size = 3822 MB (3913508 KB)
[   26.284493] block drbd0: recounting of set bits took additional 1 jiffies
[   26.284524] block drbd0: 0 KB (0 bits) marked out-of-sync by on disk bit-map.
[   26.284578] block drbd0: disk( Attaching -> Consistent )
[   26.284623] block drbd0: attached to UUIDs DF273E4A603D84AE:0000000000000000:05A4CC7381C320C6:05A3CC7381C320C7
[   27.233543] drbd nfs: conn( StandAlone -> Unconnected )
[   27.236822] drbd nfs: Starting receiver thread (from drbd_w_nfs [456])
[   27.237451] DLM installed
[   27.283266] drbd nfs: receiver (re)started
[   27.283370] drbd nfs: conn( Unconnected -> WFConnection )
[   27.836645] drbd nfs: Handshake successful: Agreed network protocol version 101
[   27.836667] drbd nfs: Feature flags enabled on protocol level: 0x7 TRIM THIN_RESYNC WRITE_SAME.
[   27.839020] drbd nfs: Peer authenticated using 20 bytes HMAC
[   27.840057] drbd nfs: conn( WFConnection -> WFReportParams )
[   27.840088] drbd nfs: Starting ack_recv thread (from drbd_r_nfs [480])
[   27.893199] block drbd0: drbd_sync_handshake:
[   27.893232] block drbd0: self DF273E4A603D84AE:0000000000000000:05A4CC7381C320C6:05A3CC7381C320C7 bits:0 flags:0
[   27.893251] block drbd0: peer DF273E4A603D84AE:0000000000000000:05A4CC7381C320C7:05A3CC7381C320C7 bits:0 flags:0
[   27.893266] block drbd0: uuid_compare()=0 by rule 40
[   27.893320] block drbd0: peer( Unknown -> Secondary ) conn( WFReportParams -> Connected ) disk( Consistent -> UpToDate ) pdsk( DUnknown -> UpToDate )
[   34.963572] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
[40620.787317] gfs2: GFS2 installed
[40907.496910] block drbd0: role( Secondary -> Primary )
[41161.493128] gfs2: can't find protocol lock_dlm
```

Comment: Turns out, its almost definitely something to do with `CONFIG_GFS2_FS_LOCKING_DLM`
I found a question at stackexchange that solved the same issue by recompiling the kernel: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439311/unable-to-mount-gfs2-file-system-on-debian-stretch-probable-dlm-mis-config

However, they failed to provide any details of how they did this smoothly. I have tried, and its been quite frustrating. If anyone knows how I can move forward with this, I'd really appreciate the help. :)

Comment: Before you go very far, you should check the obvious: that the mount point `/data` actually exists.

Comment: Please see the update in my original question, which shows that I have indeed checked that the `/data/` dir exists.

Also, I'm becoming more skeptical about the `Lock Table: "nfs:nfs"` option specified as `-t` when formatting GFS2 in `mkfs.gfs2 -p lock_dlm -j 2 -t nfs:nfs /dev/drbd0`. My stonith cluster is created as `nfs` but I'm trying to find out more about the specific nature of this particular `-t` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I use default unmodified [Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and just load the modules:

```
rpi ~$ sudo modprobe dlm
rpi ~$ sudo modprobe gfs2
```

Both modules are loaded without any problems:

```
rpi ~$ lsmod | egrep 'dlm|gfs2'
dlm                   180224  0
gfs2                  380928  0
```

Then you should check if the mountpoint is available:

```
rpi ~$ sudo ls -al /data/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 18 21:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Jan 18 21:00 ..
```

Now you should be able to mount:

```
rpi ~$ sudo mount -t gfs2 -o noatime,nodiratime,noquota /dev/drbd0 /data
```

I cannot test it because I do not have a **gfs2** file system but there is no need to compile modules. It should work out of the box with default Raspbian.

Comment: Thanks for responding @ingo, I have tried rebuilding the whole stack from scratch. I took great care to double check each step and I've added the output to my original question if you'd like to take a look. I'm kind of stuck as to how I can get around this `gfs2: can't find protocol lock_dlm` error.

Comment: @Kareem I had a look at your update, very informative. It gives me an idea that you are using a **D**istributed **R**eplicated **B**lock **D**evice (DRBD) on a Highly Available NFS Storage. Interesting but I do not have any experience on this so I'm afraid I cannot help much. Because you can successful make the filesystem on `/dev/drbd0` it seems the block device is OK. Because DRBD uses NFS I would look at the NFS configuration. The problem seems to be blocking and NFS in general has options about blocking.

Comment: no I think there is a misunderstanding @ingo. Any mention of `nfs` is purely semantic, as I have been intending this to eventually run NFS on top. The clusters are simply named "nfs".

***Please be assured that NFS is not running anywhere.*** This is a dual-primary `DRDB` volume at `/dev/drbd0` which has `pacemaker` running for `stonith`/`fencing`.

The `pacemaker` is working, and the `/dev/drbd0` volume is functional, as I have been able to use it fine with `ocfs2`, but `gfs2` continues to be an issue.

Does this help?

Comment: @Kareem No sorry, doesn't help.

Comment: Is there anything further I can try to explain to help add clarification @ingo? I updated the original question with more information about the setup.

I'm really just trying to get this `gfs2` setup working.

It seems to me like I will need to recompile the kernel to set the `CONFIG_GFS2_FS_LOCKING_DLM=y` option. I'm not sure exactly how to do that yet, but I'm trying to find out. If there is another way, I'd really like to find out.

Comment: @Kareem Please don't understand me wrong, but a Raspberry Pi is made for education and to learn the basics about hardware and software. Using a distributed high available file system with pacemaker is an issue for enterprises but not for Raspberry Pi. Please ask your question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or maybe better at https://serverfault.com/. With lack of my experience about this I cannot help.

Comment: Thanks @ingo, I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately, this question was created in severfault.com, and was moved here by one of the mods. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

You're right in the concerns of a Raspberry Pi, and I agree. I'm using my RPis at home, in my own environment, and this is for my own education more than anything else. Thanks again.